# Boost spirit 2.5.2 standalone

Tags: c++, boost, boost-spirit

Has there been a standalone package for Spirit for version 2 and above? The last standalone found on spirit's website has been 1.8.5. Or is there a way I can extract only the required dependencies for Spirit from the latest version?

Answer (score 1):

You can use BCP to extract the Spirit library (and it's dependencies).

However, it wouldn't gain you much. Spirit libraries are already header-only as they are (although if you enable thread-safety, it will require boost-thread too).

So you don't actually gain much from "removing" the unused headers. It's not like the header files are large and the ones that aren't used are... unused anyways.

Comment: Ah okay thanks. Yea Spirit is header only but boost as a whole does have quite a fair bit of libraries, no? Was trying to avoid having to include the whole of boost when Spirit is the only thing I'd be using from that.

Comment: Since it's header only you don't even have to build a single of those libraries. Just get boost, extract the archive and you're done.